# Transfer to recipient which doesn't exist

Tags: nearprotocol

When sender issues a `Transfer` action, runtime subtracts a `deposit`, issues `receipt` and node routes it to another shard.

What happens if recipient account doesn't exist? Will tokens be refunded back to the sender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Runtime generates a refund receipt from a sender `system` with a single action `Transfer` for the total amount of `deposit`.